# Дубовый бор

Tags: стилистика

Можно ли говорить "дубовый бор"?

Comment: @Наиля, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Бор - это хвойный лес. Поэтому нельзя сказать "дубовый бор".

Answer (score 0):

Можно сказать "дубовая роща", а бор - хвойный лес, его корень восходит к индоевр.
 корню *bher - "быть острым", "колоть, резать".

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, по происхождению ***бор*** = «то, что колет».

> Первичное значение «хвоя» («то, что
>   колет»), затем — «хвойное дерево,
>   сосна» (ср. др.-рус. *боръ* «сосна») и
>   далее — «хвойный лес». Последнее
>   значение возникло у слова *бор* в связи
>   с бортничеством; см. *сосна*.
>
> *Школьный этимологический словарь
>   русского языка. Происхождение слов. —
>   М.: Дрофа. Н. М. Шанский, Т. А.
>   Боброва. 2004.*
>
> http://etymological.academic.ru/317

То же и здесь:

> Интересно, что слово *борода*
>   родственно слову *бор,* в смысловой
>   основе того и другого лежат колющие
>   свойства в первом случае волос, во
>   втором – хвои.
>
> *Этимологический словарь русского языка. — СПб.: ООО "Виктория плюс".
>   Крылов Г. А.. 2004.*
>
> http://krylov.academic.ru/268/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80

Но утверждать на основании происхождения слова *бор* невозможности сочетания "дубовый бор", по-моему, нельзя.

Почему?

Сочетание это широко используется в худ. литературе:

> *Возвышенное настроение продержалось у Гоголя еще некоторое время, когда они,
>   вытащив человек на сушу, вскарабкались
>   на крутой берег и из-под палящего зноя
>   окунулись в тенистую сень векового
>   **дубового бора**.* [В. П. Авенариус. Гоголь-студент (1898)]
>
> *Там, где сейчас грохотал поезд, у подножия сопки, в густом **дубовом
>   бору**, заросшем багульником и
>   жасмином, мы летом не раз атаковали
>   невидимого врага или отлеживались в
>   обороне, вдыхая запах тайги. [Николай
>   Атаров.  Повесть о первой любви:
>   рассказы (1962) ]*

О каких именно *борах* говорят авторы?.. Возможно, об этих:

> Бор, сосновый лес, произрастающий
>   преимущественно на сухой песчаной
>   почве… На более богатых супесчаных и
>   суглинистых почвах развиваются сложные
>   Б. двух-, трёхпородного состава (сосна
>   с елью, **сосна с дубом**, сосна с
>   липой и лещиной)…
>
> *Большая советская энциклопедия. — М.: Советская энциклопедия. 1969—1978.*
>
> http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/bse/70492/%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80

Похоже на то, что **сложные боры состава "сосна с дубом"** называются именно ***дубовыми борами***, и причём не только в художественной литературе.

См. 
https://books.google.ru/books?id=UcIZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%22&dq=%22%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=up3XVL7gNIjnygOlu4LwAQ&redir_esc=y
 :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Коль скоро есть дубрава, то и дубовый бор (мужественный аналог) быть должен. Хотя подряд два "бо" не комильфо.